# How to replace some rows values with the value of another one?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame like this :

```
df <- data.frame("F" = c("N°", "X", "X", "Total", "N°", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Total"), "N" = c("6", "123", "123", "123", "8", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123"))
```

In my example the "X" isn't a real "X" is just to replace what could be in cell.

I've been using a loop to achieve that but I want to avoid that, in the case I have a very large data frame so I'm looking for a function or other method to achieve that.

And the result I expect is :

```
df <- data.frame("F" = c("N°", "6", "6", "Total", "N°", "8", "8", "8", "8", "Total"), "N" = c("6", "123", "123", "123", "8", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a grouping column based on the occurrence of "N" in the F column by doing the cumulative sum of logical vector ('grp'), then `replace` the 'X' values in 'F' with the `first` element of 'N', `ungroup` and remove the grouping variable

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(grepl("^N", F))) %>%
   mutate(F =  replace(as.character(F), 
         !F %in% c("N°", "Total"), first(as.character(N)))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   F     N    
#   <chr> <fct>
# 1 N°    6    
# 2 6     123  
# 3 6     123  
# 4 Total 123  
# 5 N°    8    
# 6 8     123  
# 7 8     123  
# 8 8     123  
# 9 8     123  
#10 Total 123
```

Comment: I get your method but like I said the "X" in the column "F" isn't a "X" is just a way of saying that it's a variable it could be anything

Comment: @Arkning  If it could be anything, you can replace it with `!F %in% c("N°", "Total")`